# Category tree in Laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to develop a website that will allow items to be posted under certain categories. The categories will almost always have at least one parent category though, and I'd like to be able to display a 'tree' of these categories for users to be able to navigate the categories and articles. A category DB would contain the columns `id`, `parent_id`, `cat_name`.

Is there a more efficient way to do this in laravel rather than looking for the top level categories then looping round to find all the sub categories in each? Where is the best place to carry out the logic and what's the best way to pass this information to the view?

If more clarification is needed let me know. Like I say I'm pretty new to laravel and frameworks in general so I'm maybe missing something obvious.

Answer (score 3):

You can define relations in Laravel to automatically load the relations of an object.

See the doc about [Relations](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships) and [Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading)

```
class Category extends Eloquent
{
    public function subcategories() {
        return $this->hasMany('Category','parent_id');
    }
}
```

In your controller:

```
Category::with('subcategories')->get(); //Get all categories and their subcategories
```

You might even do (altough I'm not sure) `Category::with('subcategories.subcategories');`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I learned about relations last night and figured it would require that, but the Eager Loading stuff is new to me. My understanding is, that this would work but only one level deep? How would I make something to display the second/third/fourth level's sub-categories? Or am I missing something...

Answer (score 1):

Handling a Nested Set manually is pretty arduous. I suggest you use an existing package:

### [Baum](https://github.com/etrepat/baum)

> Baum is an implementation of the [Nested Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) pattern for Laravel 4's Eloquent ORM.

Comment: Yeah, I found this in my hunt for a solution. I'd really like to just get a firm grip of Laravel itself first though before I start throwing in extra packages.